# My sound not works in GA-945GCMX-S2

Tags: sound

```
henrique@Henrique-Bodhi-5:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:05.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
Bhenrique@Henrique-Bodhi-5:~$ lsmod
Module Size Used by
rtl8188fu 1273856 0
cfg80211 622592 1 rtl8188fu
input_leds 16384 0
joydev 24576 0
gpio_ich 16384 0
snd_hda_codec_realtek 102400 1
snd_hda_codec_generic 73728 1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel 40960 2
snd_hda_codec 126976 3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
serio_raw 16384 0
lpc_ich 24576 0
snd_hda_core 81920 4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep 20480 1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm 98304 3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer 32768 1 snd_pcm
snd 81920 11 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore 16384 1 snd
mac_hid 16384 0
sch_fq_codel 20480 6
binfmt_misc 20480 1
it87 57344 0
hwmon_vid 16384 1 it87
coretemp 16384 0
parport_pc 36864 1
ppdev 20480 0
lp 20480 0
parport 49152 3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables 28672 0
x_tables 40960 1 ip_tables
autofs4 40960 2
btrfs 1122304 0
xor 24576 1 btrfs
zstd_compress 163840 1 btrfs
raid6_pq 114688 1 btrfs
dm_mirror 24576 0
dm_region_hash 20480 1 dm_mirror
dm_log 20480 2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
hid_microsoft 16384 0
usbhid 49152 0
hid 118784 2 usbhid,hid_microsoft
i915 1617920 7
vídeo 40960 1 i915
i2c_algo_bit 16384 1 i915
drm_kms_helper 167936 1 i915
psmouse 147456 0
pata_acpi 16384 0
r8169 86016 0
syscopyarea 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
mii 16384 1 r8169
drm 401408 9 i915,drm_kms_helper
henrique@Henrique-Bodhi-5:~$
```

I use Body Linux 4.15.0-20 ( by Ubuntu ).

Pavucontrol show output ficticius.

I reinstall pulseaudio, pavucontrol and alsamixer but not solved.

In PartedMagic live the sound work fine:

```
~# lsmod
ModuleSizeUsedby
ext4 2493391
mbcache 34201 ext4
jbd2 460321 ext4
snd_seq_dummy 9160
snd_seq_oss 207990
snd_seq_midi_event 34551 snd_seq_oss
snd_seq 334835 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device 34573 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq
snd_pcm_oss 260250
snd_mixer_oss 92971 snd_pcm_oss
bluetooth 543342
rfkill 94461 bluetooth
ipv6 18426422
nfsd 1795698
exportfs 25031 nfsd
dm_mod 457330
fuse 462361
isofs 242320
joydev 63760
usbhid 240291
snd_hda_codec_realtek 1924281
hid 529391 usbhid
i915 2727392
sg 162280
snd_hda_intel 151841
drm_kms_helper 175571 i915
drm 1243883 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd_hda_codec 472562 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
pata_acpi 18040
i2c_algo_bit 33861 i915
intel_agp 70241 i915
ppdev 39280
snd_hwdep 35661 snd_hda_codec
mac_hid 21000
vídeo 87941 i915
ata_generic 21400
processor 200250
r8169 265440
intel_gtt 85733 i915,intel_agp
evdev 59329
parport_pc 149130
snd_pcm 435663 snd_pcm_oss,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
thermal_sys 91162 vídeo,processor
button 31541 i915
uhci_hcd 148040
snd_timer 117662 snd_seq,snd_pcm
rtc_cmos 56520
parport 209562 ppdev,parport_pc
ehci_hcd 263520
mii 28881 r8169
agpgart 182803 drm,intel_agp,intel_gtt
ata_piix 171561
snd 3338313 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_timer
i2c_i801 59960
psmouse 376470
serio_raw 26200
soundcore 33921 snd
hwmon 10301 thermal_sys
snd_page_alloc 49092 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
```

Any solution ?

Thanks !